# Flutter image.asset lags on showing GIF image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to show a gif image in flutter but when i am playing it, it starts lagging and its element move it leaves its colur in the background,

i have used
`Image.asset('assets\animation.gif')`
is there any better way to display it in flutter since in gif there is no issue on viewing it from phone or pc, i have used many Libraries and widgets in flutter??

[image]

Comment: Maybe reducing the resolution of the GIF file could solve the problem.